# Vantage of dialogflow integration with whatsapp business

Tags: twilio, dialogflow-es, chatbot, whatsapp, dialogflow-cx

I'm trying to create a chatbot in Whatsapp business and I read that the best and easiest way to do that is using Twilio. I also read that a lot of people integrate this service with Dialogflow but what are the vantage of doing that? what can I do with that infrastructure and what is the limitation with only Whatsapp business and Twilio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say chatbot, the assumption is you want to create a two-way human-to-bot interaction. So, it comes does to the experience of the chatbot interaction.

If you use a tool like [Twilio Studio](https://www.twilio.com/studio) and WhatsApp, you can have an interaction but the dialog from the bot follows a specific path, where you offer the person an option to choose.

If you want a more natural dialog, where the person can ask anything rather then offering them a choice to choose from, you need a tool like [Twilio Autopilot](https://www.twilio.com/autopilot) of Dialogflow to handle that organic non-linear flow.

Autopilot and Dialogflow match up what the person says with tasks or intents which result in actions/events.

Comment: As @Alan states, Dialogflow is to handle the organic non-linear flow on your chatbot. I could suggest to take a look at the Dialogflow documentation, in particular the [basics](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/basics) section, also the [concepts](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/concepts) for more details, and finally for something practical take a look at the [quickstarts](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/quick).